# Does looping animations crash browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have some PNG's being moved around a screen in a repeated loop which I believe may be crashing some browsers.

For example:

```
function parachute_drop(drop_object, animation_duration) {

    $(drop_object)
        .animate({top: "750px"},animation_duration)
        .animate({top:"-150px", opacity: 100
        },{
        duration: 0, 
        complete: function(){
            parachute_drop(drop_object,animation_duration);
        }
    });
 }

 parachute_drop('#object_id',10000);
```

Everytime the animation completes, it launches the function again and into infinity.

I didn't forsee this would be problematic but I have heard that this is not very good and well, my site is now crashing after some time it seems.

Is there a way to do endless loops like this in a more stable manner? It seems a bit bizarre that simply moving a 9kb png file from the top to the bottom of the screen over and over again is a strain on system resources. Whats the issue and how do I approach this better?

Comment: Look in to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Comment: @Switz: jQUery is using that for him.

Comment: Instead of showing animation by looping, you would better look into some javascript gaming libraries like jawsjs, impact, gamequery etc. More info can be found here: https://gist.github.com/768272

Comment: one fix is use a setTimeout with duration really low, even 1 before calling the function again

Comment: @charlietfl: There's no point; jQuery is already doing that.

Comment: @SLaks are you saying there should be nothing wrong or resource vacuuming about the above function?

Comment: I thought so...  have used this looping animation method numerous times myself before

Comment: @cosmicbdog: Continually running an animation will consume resources, period.  I don't really recommend it.  However, your code is optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a recursive algorithm and may crash when then fill up the code stack of the javascript machine of the browser. You can use a different approach based on timer to achieve a continuous loop.

You can start from this example : http://www.irengba.com/codewell/

Comment: I see - thanks for that. I was following that tutorial but somebody suggested I make my own function and just call it within itself. It seemed like thats what this tutorial is doing either but must be using a different method?

Comment: That is not true.  @cosmicbdog's code is asynchronous, not recursive.

Comment: The animation is asynchronous based on Jquery code but the completed method is a chaining argument and may be unstable if they never complete de chaining methode like a recursive one.

Comment: I put my repeated animations into everytime() functions from the code above and still get the browser crashes.

Comment: I think I discovered the problem... the everytime() function has a interval setting I had set to 10. My loops however were minutes long. So they were stacking up every 10 seconds - does that sound right? I struggle a bit understanding the lingo of jquery coders for some reason.